# Configuring SessionState with remote configSource file

Tags: asp.net, session-state, sql-session-state

In my web.config I have:

```
<sessionState configSource="SessionState.config">
</sessionState>
```

In SessionState.config I have:

```
<sessionState  timeout="90" mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" cookieless="false" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=.;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=True">
</sessionState>
```

I've tried various incantations but can't seem to get it to work. I get this error:

> Parser Error Message: Unable to open
>   configSource file
>   'SessionState.config'.

From MSDN:

[image]

Of course they don't show an actual example.

I verified that the file is in the bin directory. I also have this working fine for the connection strings section.

How do I use a remote config file for sessionState?

Thanks,

Rick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SessionState.config file should NOT be in the bin directory but should be in the same directory as the web.config

Comment: I just figured that out. If I change my config source to configSource="bin\SessionState.config" it works fine.

Comment: I modified my App.config and Web.config to both use configSource="bin\connections.config" and that ressolved this issue.